# Android Application Crashes With Orientation Changes

Tags: android

I have an Android page containg 3 images a background and edit text and button, and the manifest file the activity given as:

```
<activity
     Android:name="SearchScreen"
     >
</activity>
```

I have two XML one for potrait and another for landscape.
when orientation changes there is no problem for first some changes but when it changes frequently some more time the application crashes and the error seems like this

```
> Android.view.InflateException on orientation change
```

and also give some VM memory out of bounds.

and the error log is like bellow

```
 11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.af.screenmanager/com.af.screenmanager.SearchScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class <unknown>
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2853)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:121)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:947)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class <unknown>
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.setContentView(FragmentActivity.java:304)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at com.af.screenmanager.SearchScreen.onCreate(SearchScreen.java:131)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    ... 12 more
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    ... 24 more
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:494)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:715)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1720)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:585)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:805)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:746)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1705)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1975)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:370)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
    11-21 15:09:55.832: E/AndroidRuntime(32448):    ... 27 more
```

This error ocurs with sony erricson Xperia only

Comment: android.view.InflateException would mean that you got exception in an inflater in your code

Comment: Need code and\or xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Add to your activity in manifest the following code

```
<activity android:name="SearchScreen"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
</activity>
```

You can also use Async task to make this happen so that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have heavy bitmaps in your layout try calling recycle for them in activity's onDestory method

```
@Override 
public void onDestroy(){
    ImageView imageViewWithHeavyBitmap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    imageViewWithHeavyBitmap.getDrawable().getBitmap().recycle();
}
```